# SublimeSBT not recognising project

Tags: scala, sbt, sublimetext3

I've been working on many Scala projects using Eclipse with Scala Plugin, Scala IDE and IntelliJ with Scala plugin but recently I decided to give Sublime Text 3 + SublimeSBT a go due to the slugishness of the IDEs.

My problem is that SublimeText3 doesn't recognise my project as an SBT one.

- I downloaded the package using Package Control.
- I have tested it on one of my working projects (they both work in Scala IDE and
  command line SBT).
- Invocation of ctrl+shift+p in SublText doesn't recognise any sbt commands (only SBT: Clear history)

I am using Windows 8 x64.

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out. For future reference - make sure to include the entire project directory in your sublime text sidebar so that it containes not only .scala files but also build.sbt. If you include just text files it will treat them as such and not part of the project

Answer (score 0):

SublimeSBT seems pretty fussy about how you open up the folder project. As you say, you need to make sure that in Sublime you're opening up build.sbt as well as the .scala files. So opening from the root folder of a normally configured project works ok. However, if you open it in sublime from, say, the parent of this root folder, then again SublimeSBT won't recognize it. I'd guess (without having tested exhaustively) that build.sbt needs to be one level down from the top folder in sublime.